Postgresql find fd total, used, available
Does PostgreSQL have any function or table that provides information on the total, used, and available file descriptors for each process?
pg_settings gives info of total fd per each server process.
postgres=# SELECT * FROM pg_settings WHERE name = 'max_files_per_process' ;
-[ RECORD 1 ]---+------------------------------------------------------------------------------
name            | max_files_per_process
setting         | 1000
unit            | 
category        | Resource Usage / Kernel Resources
short_desc      | Sets the maximum number of simultaneously open files for each server process.
extra_desc      | 
context         | postmaster
vartype         | integer
source          | default
min_val         | 25
max_val         | 2147483647
enumvals        | 
boot_val        | 1000
reset_val       | 1000
sourcefile      | 
sourceline      | 
pending_restart | f

Is there a table in PostgreSQL that stores information about used and available file descriptors?
